# Not permitted to access my files on $HOME in tmux after log out and log in

Tags: kerberos

My $HOME on a server  is in a Andrew file system,  and the server runs kerberos.

I created a tmux session, wherein I ran a shell process. Then I detached it, and logged out, and after a while logged in again and reattach the tmux session. 
In the shell process in tmux, I found that I didn't have permission to access my (non-directory) files in $HOME. I checked my ticket and it didn't expire, and I renewed it by running `krenew` and still didn't have permission.

```
$ ls -l
ls: cannot access README: Permission denied
ls: cannot access setup.sh: Permission denied
ls: cannot access setup.sh~: Permission denied
total 14
drwxrwxr-x.  2 t 2048 Apr  6 21:48 bin
drwxrwxr-x. 11 t 2048 Apr 24 18:16 data
???????????  ? ?    ?     ?            ? README.md
???????????  ? ?    ?     ?            ? setup.sh
???????????  ? ?    ?     ?            ? setup.sh~
drwxrwxr-x.  2 t 2048 Apr 22 18:50 src
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The dirty solution is to update tmux's value for `$KRB5CCNAME`. First,
run this **outside tmux:**

```
$ echo $KRB5CCNAME
FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_201108_XXXXXX
```

Then, **inside tmux,** you need to export that new value:

```
$ export KRB5CCNAME='FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_201108_XXXXXX'
```

Now, tmux has your new credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a valid ticket, but you most likely don't have valid AFS tokens.  Try running `aklog` to get tokens from your existing cached credentials.  Check the output of `tokens` to see if you have valid tokens.  Make sure that with your krenew that you run aklog (which is simply an [additional parameter](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/kstart/krenew.html) to krenew).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean solution that worked for me. Log into any tmux session and -

```
$ kinit
$ aklog
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked for me.